# Рисование в PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt4

В приложении создано окно, написанное в **PyQt4** на **Python 3.3**. Я создаю переопределение события paintEvent и рисую, например, эллипс:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    self.paint_ = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    self.paint_.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("#000"), 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, QtCore.Qt.RoundCap))
    self.paint_.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("#fc6c2d"), QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))

    self.paint_.drawEllipse(300, 300, 500, 500)

    self.paint_.end()
```

Как я понял - рисование при помощи QPainter возможно только в области события **paintEvent**. В таком случае возникает вопрос - если, например, мне необходимо "дорисовать" к уже имеющемуся виду, например, линию - как это возможно сделать?

Я нашел не очень хороший, но все же выходи из ситуации (при помощи if конструкций и вызова события

```
def NewLine(p1, p2):
    self.newLine = True
    self.P = [p1, p2]
    self.repaint()

def paintEvent( ... ):
    ...
    if newLine:
        self.paint.drawLine(self.P[0][0], self.P[0][1], self.P[1][0], self.P[1][1]
    ...
)
```

Но качество этого *велосипеда* по прежнему оставляет желать лучшего. Есть ли иной способ "дорисовки"?

Comment: Действительно, возможно я не умею точно и доступно формулировать мысли =\

Попробую подробнее.

Comment: "Как я понял - рисование при помощи QPainter возможно только в области события paintEvent." Неправда, QPainter может рисовать где угодно и на чем угодно, например на QPixmap или QImage

Answer (score 1):

Надо создать несколько методов, которые и будут рисовать. И их вызывать из paintEvent. Пример:

```
def paintEvent(self, e):
    self.sk = QtGui.QPainter()
    self.sk.begin()
    self.drawBack()
    self.drawStars()
    self.sk.end()

def drawBack(self): #, qp):
    white_pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor('white'), 3)
    self.sk.setPen(white_pen)
    self.sk.setBrush(QtGui.QColor('midnightblue'))
    self.sk.drawRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

def drawStars(self):
    self.sk.setPen(QtGui.QColor('white'))
    size = self.size()

 for i in range(10):
        x = random.randint(1, size.width()-1)
        y = random.randint(1, size.height()-1)
        self.sk.drawPoint(x, y)
```

Comment: Не совсем мне понятно. Зачем ссылку на QPainter хранить в поле? Если и хранить, то создавать новый объект при каждом вызове paintEvent точно не нужно. Да и при создании QPainter, в его конструктор достаточно передать объект на который он будет рисовать, в данном случае это окно виджета, т.е. self. И если передавать в конструктор, то не нужно вызывать метод begin. Метод end тоже можно не вызывать, если в конце функции QPainter нарисовал все, что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Тыкаете на окно и в нем рисуются круги.

Алгоритм простой – все фигуры рисуем на `QImage` через метод `mouseReleaseEvent`, а в событии рисования просто отрисовываем `QImage`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(300, 300)

        self._im = QtGui.QImage(self.width(), self.height(), QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self._im.fill(QtGui.QColor("white"))

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self._im)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("#000000"), 1, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, QtCore.Qt.RoundCap))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("#fc6c2d"), QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawEllipse(event.pos(), 10, 10)

        # Перерисуемся
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self._im)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = Widget()
widget.setWindowTitle('simple')
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

Когда-то делал [рисовалку](https://github.com/gil9red/fake-painter) на python3 + PySide (модуль для работы с Qt, аналог PyQt4). Возможно, пригодится :)

Comment: PyCharm почему-то не может влезть в исходники PyQt4, чтобы выводить подсказки по доступным методам/полям, сам использую PySide, с которым нет такой проблемы, поэтому сделал такой мизер, даже без сглаживания QPainter -- очень уже неудобно.